# Is it possible to open an Outlook attachment without saving it?

Tags: vba

I'm working on an Excel workbook that scans an Outlook folder, pulls the email data and saves the attachment. A later bit of code then reads the data in each attachment and prints it to a master sheet.

I really want to remove the need to save an attachment and just temporarily open it, take what I need from it and then close it.

I've done a fair bit of research and can't find anything that doesn't involve saving it. It's also worth calling out Outlook VBA is out of the question due to security restrictions so it needs to be done from Excel.

Is it possible to do what I want, and do you have any examples/references I can check out?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. To display/open/read the data you need to save it. Even when you preview it inside Outlook, the file is saved at temp location.

You can always save the file (preferably in User's Temp folder) and after processing the file you can delete it from VBA.

To Delete the a file from VBA , use `Kill` Command. Make sure the file is closed and then

`Kill` FullFileName

Example: `Kill "C:\Temp\abc.xlsx"`

Comment: Thanks @cyboashu. In terms of efficiency, would it be better to save file > open file > copy from file > loop or save file> loop for x > open file > copy from file > loop for x?